# My father (US citizen) won't take reponsibility for me

Tags: usa, immigration

My father is a US citizen, my mother is a Rwandese refugee. My father abandoned us. Where can I get help to oblige my father to take responsibility for me? I'm 12 years old and can't get school fees.

Comment: Are you and your mother presently in the USA or are you living elsewhere?

Comment: I think you are outside the USA since you mention needing school fees and public school is free in the USA. Are there any legal or refugee support services near you? Also, do you know if your father has a job? He won't be able to support you if he does not have one.

Comment: you have to prove that the guy is your father first. Is your mom and dad married? Do they have a marriage certificate? Do you have a birth certificate with the name of your father mentioned? Do you know where your father is currently, i.e do you have his address?